# Simulating page transition animation when showing a Grid in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

I have a Windows 10 (UWP) app with a few screens in a `SplitView`. When navigating among pages a page transition animation is shown (I added animations to the `SplitView`'s `Frame`).

One page of the app is a bit different. In the left half a calendar is shown. In the right half a detail for a day is shown. When a user taps a day in the calendar (on the left), the detail is shown on the right.

When the windows is narrow or the app runs on a phone, only the calendar or the day are shown. So the users sees the calendar, taps on a day and the calendar hides (Visibility=Collapsed) and the day detail shows (Visibility=Visible). And vice versa on back key press.

The problem is that this feels awkward, because there is no animation that would look like transitioning from calendar to day.

So the question is, how to simulate a page transition animation when showing a Grid?

I took a look at the UWP sample for a master-detail scenario (my situation is basically a master-detail scenario). In the sample Microsoft has two pages instead of on, a master page with a list and a detail and a separate, duplicated, detail page. And a ton of ugly code behind for navigating depending on screen size, manipulation the back stack when windows size changes and so on. Not really an elegant solution.

Comment: Did you solve your problem somehow? I'm dealing with the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about an elegant solution to simulate a navigation transition, but I wouldn't use `Visibility`. It doesn't play well with animations.

I'd consider using something like a `Transform` animation to offset the two element by one screen width. I won't simulate a navigation transition, but it'll be better than a jarring switch.

Alternatively you could simulate something like the `Pivot` transition when it changes tabs.